# Does array.filter() create a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

**as per document says** The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

According to document below script should console `Learning`
 **console.log(Arr[0].name) // Learning**

```
var Arr = [{name:'Learning'},{name:'Questing'}]
var Arr2 = Arr.filter(it=> true);
Arr2[0].name = 'Stack-Over-Flow';
console.log(Arr[0].name) // Stack-Over-Flow
```

Comment: It creates a new array but it does not make deep-copies of the array contents. The objects are referenced in both the original and the new array.

Comment: It's a new array as in `Arr2.pop()` will not affect `Arr`. The objects are still the same `Arr[0] === Arr2[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `.filter` creates a new array, but the *new array* is the only new structure that is created. The items *inside* the array remain unchanged.

With your code, after filtering, you have a *new* array which contains 2 items, where both of those items are references to *the same objects* that were in the original array. So, mutating one of the objects in the new array results in the objects in the old array being mutated, because they point to the same object in memory.

If you wanted to avoid this, you'd have to deep clone the array first, perhaps with

```
const Arr2 = Arr
  .filter(it => true)
  .map(obj => ({ ...obj }));
```

Comment: your answer  sounds interesting but documentation says it create new array

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari which is exactly what this answer says in the first line

Comment: It *does* create a new array (like my answer says in the first sentence) - *but the new array is the only new structure that is created*

Comment: If it is creating new array than i am not able to understand why it modifies the old array

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari you have to differentiate between *new array* (container for items) and *new objects* (items that go in the container). `.filter()` creates the former, not the latter.

Comment: It does not modify the the old array, it modifies an *object which exists in both the old and new array*.

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari It modifies the *objects* in the old array. It does not modify the old array itself - the old array still contains the same 2 items. The array container is new, the items contained in the old array remain in the old array, but the same items are put into the new array as well, so changing one of the items in the new array results in the old array looking different as well - despite the fact that the old array container has not been changed.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter` does create a new array, but the array of the filtered elements from the old array.

While the element from the old is object, so that new array still keep its reference. To avoid that, you could do a `.map` to clone the element for the whole new reference

```js
var Arr = [{name:'Learning'},{name:'Questing'}]
var Arr2 = Arr.filter(it=> true).map(el => ({...el}));
Arr2[0].name = 'Stack-Over-Flow';
console.log(Arr[0].name)
```

Comment: so arr.filter holds the reference ?

Comment: @IshwarChandraTiwari object values are *always* its reference. If you do `a = {foo: 1}; b = a` you still have *one* object but two different variables for it. `b.bar = 2; console.log(a)` will still print `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`