# Why do filter method implementations create another array instead of modifying the current array?

Tags: arrays, computer-science

From what I know, many popular implementations of filter collection methods, e.g. JavaScript's [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, tend to [create a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63941282/does-array-filter-create-a-new-array) rather than modifying it. (As @Berthur mentioned, this is also generally useful in terms of functional programming as well).

However, from what I've seen in homemade methods of filter implementations, sometimes the author chooses to use a while / for loop on a dynamically allocated array (e.g. an ArrayList in Java) and remove elements instead.

I have a general idea of why this is the case (since removing elements requires the rest of the array's elements afterwards to be shifted over, which is O(n) while adding elements is O(1)), *but* I also know that in the same case, if an element is added to the end of an array when the array is full, it requires memory to be allocated, which requires, in the case for [Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-arraylist-in-java/), the array to be copied.

Thus, is there some mathematical reason of why creating a new array for filtering is (generally) faster than removing & moving elements over, or is it just for the guaranteed immutability over the original array that it guarantees?

Comment: I did also consider that but noticed that #filter occasionally results in shallow copies in some languages. However, I didn't take into account programming languages centered around functional programming too - thanks! I'll edit my question accordingly with this info.

Comment: True, because of how it is defined on abstract level. It just creates a new data structure with the same elements: If those elements are in turn references to objects, then the returned array will have references too, like a shallow copy would. In Javascript, for instance, you can call `filter` on a normal array, but also on a [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), and expect the same behaviour. However, typed arrays are not resizable so it would not even be possible in the first place to perform an in-place filter.

Comment: This was becoming a lot of text so I put it in an answer instead, though there might be more aspects to this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not generally faster, and it's not done for performance reasons. It's more of a programming paradigm, as well as being a convenient tool.

While in-place algorithms are often faster for performance and/or memory critical applications, they need to know about the underlying implementation of the data structure, and become more specific. This immutable approach allows for more general functionality, apart from being convenient. The approach is common in [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). As you say, it guarantees immutability, which makes it compatible with this way of thinking.

In your Javascript example, for instance, notice that you can call `filter` on a regular array, but you could also call it on a [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). Now, typed arrays cannot be resized, so performing an in-place filter would not be possible in the first place. But the `filter` method behaves in the same way through their common interface, following the principles of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Ultimately, these functions are just available to you and while they can be very convenient for many cases, it is up to you as a programmer to decide whether they cover your specific need or whether you must implement your own custom algorithm.